# Creating directories from the list of folder names which is present inside a text file in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to create the directories with same name as the ones which are present inside a text file.I want to create separate directories by reading each names inside a text file.

Basically the text file is a dump of all directory names.

```
dir /b /o:n /ad %MYSRC%\* > ToolNames.txt

for %%x in ('ToolNames.txt') do (
 set ToolName=%%x
 mkdir %ToolName%
)
```

But the above code does not yield me the desired result. Please help

Comment: try with `for /f "delims=" %%x in (ToolNames.txt) ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%x in (ToolNames.txt) do (
 ECHO mkdir %%x
)
```

Please refer to endless articles on SO about `delayedexpansion` which will explain why your original code failed.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.